# El state se borra cuando refresco la pagina

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy en una aplicacion en la cual se esta configurando el login y logout en ella estoy utilizando context api. Para lo cual el state esta de alguna manera globalizado para que el navbar pueda actualizarse cuando el state pase de false a true. El problema sucede cuando yo refresco el sitio el navbar vuelve a el state previo al login osea false por lo que el state no persiste, he intentado pasar a localstorage el state pero no me ha resultado satisfactorio.

**navbar:**

```
         // React
    import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

    // React router
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

    // React apollo
    import * as compose from 'lodash.flowright';

    // React Components
    import LoginPage from '../../views/Login';
    import Header from '../../views/Home/Header';
    import Home from '../../views/Home';

    // React bootstrap
    import { Navbar, Form, Nav, NavDropdown, Button, FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';
    import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';

    // Mutations
    import mutations from './mutations';

    // Context 
    import { Context } from '../../context/context';

    class NavbarLayout extends React.Component {


        render() {

            return(
                <Context.Consumer>
                {c => {

                    return(
                        <Fragment>
                        <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
                        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Sample App</Navbar.Brand>
                        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                            <Nav className="ml-auto">
                            <Nav.Link><Link to="/">Home</Link></Nav.Link>
                            {localStorage.getItem('isLogged') ? 
                            (
                                <Fragment>
                                    <Nav.Link onClick={e => c.signOut(e)}>Salir</Nav.Link>
                                    <Nav.Link>Publicar</Nav.Link>
                                </Fragment>

                            ) : 
                            (
                                <Nav.Link><Link to="/sign-in">Entrar</Link></Nav.Link>
                            )}
                            </Nav>
                        </Navbar.Collapse>

                    </Navbar>

                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/sign-in" component={LoginPage} />
                </Switch>
                </Fragment>
                    );
                }}
                </Context.Consumer>
            );
        }
    }

    export default compose(
        withRouter,
        graphql(mutations.signoutUser, { name: 'signoutUser' })
    )(NavbarLayout)
```

**context:**

```
          // React
    import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

    // React apollo
    import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
    import * as compose from 'lodash.flowright';

    // React router
    import { withRouter, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

    // Mutation
    import mutations from './mutations';

    // Context
    export const Context = React.createContext();

    class AppProvider extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                // Login & logout states
                login_credentials: {},
                isLogged: false,
                get_data: this.get_data,
                submit: this.submit,
                signOut: this.signOut
            }
        }

        // Actions

        // Login & Logout

        get_data = async(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const { name, value } = e.target;
            const data = { [name]: value };
            const newData = { ...this.state.login_credentials, ...data };
            this.setState({
                login_credentials: newData
            });

        }

        submit = async(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const { signinUser } = this.props;
            const { login_credentials } = this.state;

            try {
                let variables = login_credentials;
                const response = await signinUser({variables});
                const get_token = response.data.signinUser.token;

                // setting localStorage
                localStorage.setItem('token', get_token);

                this.setState({
                    isLogged: true
                }); 

                localStorage.setItem('isLogged', this.state.isLogged);

                this.props.history.push('/');


            } catch(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }

        }


        signOut = async(e) => {

            e.preventDefault();
            const { signoutUser } = this.props;
            try {   
                await signoutUser();
                localStorage.removeItem('token');
                localStorage.removeItem('isLogged');
                this.setState({
                    isLogged: false
                });

            } catch(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
        // END LOGIN & LOGOUT ACTIONS

        render() {
            return(
                <Context.Provider value={this.state}>
                    {this.props.children}
                </Context.Provider>
            );
        }
    }

    export default compose(
        withRouter,
        graphql(mutations.signinUser, { name: 'signinUser' }),
        graphql(mutations.signoutUser, { name: 'signoutUser' })
    )(AppProvider)
```

Comment: Es obvio. El estado se guarda en memoria. Cuando recargas, se pierden los cambios que se han hecho y vuelve a su estado original. Si lo que quieres es persistir algunos datos del estado, usa [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: Hola si intente guardar en el localstorage al momento del submit y utilizarlo en el navbar pero sin éxito ya que no me actualizaba la vista del nav

Comment: Pero si no verificas si existeya un valor en el `localStorage`. Esto `isLogged: false` debe ser: `isLogged: localStorage.getItem('token') || false`.

Comment: @gugadev hice esto en el componente navbar state = {  isLogged: localStorage.getItem('token') || false  } pero el componente contrariamente se actualizara solo si lo refresco manualmente.

Comment: ¿Eso no debería ir en tu `Provider`?

Comment: si deberia, de hecho lo puse en el provider dentro de el state de arriba como:             isLogged: localStorage.getItem('token') ? true : false(lo cual me sirve solo que debo actualizar el componente a mano) y abajo tambien intente (en la funcion submit)

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con "me sirve pero debo actualizar el componente a mano"?

Comment: que cuando seteo el state desde el submit y ese es consumido por navbar director desde el consumer al ingresar este navbar se actualiza en sus elementos en el momento que entre. Ahora para que ocurra esa actualizacion debo refrescar con f5

Comment: ¿Ves algún error en la consola del navegador cuando haces el submit?

Comment: no pero me paso una cosa super rara ahora me funciona perfecto, cuando se dispara la funcion submit -> setea a true el state del context -> y cuando setea lo siguiente es que guarda ese state en el localStorage.

Lo raro :0 que cuando le doy salir dispara la funcion del context signOut -> remueve el token -> remueve el state anterior del local -> y vuelvo a setear a false el state lo que es bueno y funciona pero en ningun momento el navbar esta ahora consumiento de ese state(isLogged). pero si saco ese setState de la funcion signOut no me vuelve a actualizar el navbar cuando salgo. :0

Comment: @gugadev alli actualice el codigo a como me funciona perfectamente ahora si te das cuenta el signout remueve el state del local que lo lee el consumidor en el navbar, pero si llego a quitar el setState del signOut no funciona el codigo (osea no me actualiza el nav) es raro jaja porque no consume isLogged state

Comment: Justamente para esto esta JWT, te recomendaría que lo agregues a tu back-end y luego lo implementes en react. [En este tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ON87B1PJIlY) te enseñan a implementar el JWT en react, no es muy complicado de usar

Answer (score 0):

hola arreglada el problema era que como el state se guarda en la memoria, al actualiar la pagina este no persistia. Sin embargo lo que se hizo fue colocar ese state en localStorage aqui el codigo:

```
           this.state = {
                // Login & logout states
                login_credentials: {},
                isLogged: false,
                get_data: this.get_data,
                submit: this.submit,
                signOut: this.signOut
            }
        }

        // Actions

        // Login & Logout

        get_data = async(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const { name, value } = e.target;
            const data = { [name]: value };
            const newData = { ...this.state.login_credentials, ...data };
            this.setState({
                login_credentials: newData
            });

        }

        submit = async(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const { signinUser } = this.props;
            const { login_credentials } = this.state;

            try {
                let variables = login_credentials;
                const response = await signinUser({variables});
                const get_token = response.data.signinUser.token;

                // setting localStorage
                localStorage.setItem('token', get_token);

                this.setState({
                    isLogged: true
                }); 

                localStorage.setItem('isLogged', this.state.isLogged);

                this.props.history.push('/home');


            } catch(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }

        }


        signOut = async(e) => {

            e.preventDefault();
            const { signoutUser } = this.props;
            try {   
                await signoutUser();
                localStorage.removeItem('token');
                localStorage.removeItem('isLogged');
                this.setState({
                    isLogged: false
                });

            } catch(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
```

y para el componente navbar hacer el condicional con la data que viene desde local storage con el state actualizado.

```
              <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
                <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Sample App</Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav className="ml-auto">
                    <Nav.Link><Link to="/home">Home</Link></Nav.Link>
                    {localStorage.getItem('isLogged') ? 
                    (
                        <Fragment>
                            <Nav.Link onClick={e => c.signOut(e)}>Salir</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link>Publicar</Nav.Link>
                        </Fragment>

                    ) : 
                    (
                        <Nav.Link><Link to="/sign-in">Entrar</Link></Nav.Link>
                    )}
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>

            </Navbar>
```